# Bootstrap 3 & Masonry : Setting four colums

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I am trying to integrate the `Masonry` with `Bootstrap 3`. My goal is to display **4 items** in a row.

Without `Masonry` its showing 4 items, but after integrating `Masonry`, its showing **3 items**.

This is the js fiddle link for what I have done

JSFIDDLE Link : http://jsfiddle.net/7Lptygkn/1/

Link to the Masonry Options : http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

I set following options in the initialization :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $('#feed-list');
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.feed',
        columnWidth: '.feed',
        transitionDuration: 0
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this working? Is there anything i can help you with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this : `<div id="feed-list" class="col-xs-12">`

To this: `<div id="feed-list" class="row">`

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e8qf2cmt/

Here is a good example with tabs too: http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/mywEMR/